# how to automatic log CAN data when testing fail

Tags: capl

I'm using CAPL to make an automatic testing, I want to log CAN bus data at a point (such as testfail point), and the CAN bus data need 10 second before the point (not after the point). 
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Analysis -> Measurement setup
2. Rightclick on the right side of the measurement setup window
3. Add new logging block
4. Select toggle on and off method as CAPL
5. Set the pre-trigger time to 10 000 ms or how much you need
6. Configure output file how you need it
7. Whenever test fails you trigger the block with `startLogging(nameOfYourLoggingBlock)`
8. Remember that you need to end the logging at some point with `stopLogging(nameOfYourLoggingBlock)`

Comment: @user13063667, if this answer solves your problem, you should consider to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).